# Replace pdb natvis type definition by installed vsix natvis

Tags: vsix, natvis

We have .natvis file with basic type definitions embedded in the .pdb.
Then we have an VSIX with .natvis provides more information.

We would like to use the base .natvis when the vsix is not installed, and when the vsix is installed， use the .natvis inside it.

But the current problem is that, depending on the [.natvis files evaluate priority](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022), it will only use the file next to the pdb, regardless of whether vsix is installed or not.

Is there any solution?
Thank you very much.

I've tried the IncludeView and Priority attribute, they are only useful within the same .natvis file, not across file scopes.